# Editing data.table column in place based on row numbers within conditional subset

Tags: r, data.table

Using the mtcar dataset for demonstration.

I am flagging potential outliers in a data.table based on some model outputs and would like to increment a 'regflag' column based on row numbers ('outliernums' below, the output of my outlier detection function) within a conditional subset (cyl == 6). What would be a faster and/or more elegant/idiomatic way to do this in data.table?

```
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
outliernums <- c(1,3,5)
cars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
cars[, regflags := 0]
mbm = microbenchmark(
  imethod = cars[cyl == 6, regflags := ifelse(.I %in% outliernums, regflags+1, regflags)],
  subsetmethod = cars[which(cars$cyl == 6)[outliernums], regflags := regflags +1],
  times=1000
)
mbm
```

The output:

```
Unit: microseconds
         expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval cld
      imethod 1236.603 1721.7990 3829.3193 2322.0490 6296.972 34526.04  1000   b
 subsetmethod  284.809  423.7495  938.4575  561.7775 1519.042 11189.23  1000  a
```

I thought that the former would have been more idiomatic somehow? Any better recommendation.

Comment: Are you looking for a faster way? A better way? Your expected output is unclear to me.

Comment: I your are looking for speed and that the actual question really looks like this one then the `subsetmethod` is the most efficient. But if you want to treat all the `cyl` similarly maybe you should change the format of `outliernums`

Comment: @NelsonGon Yes, faster would be great, but it also feels clunky, so I was wondering whether there was something more elegant/idiomatic that I'm missing.

Comment: Could you add sample output showing the outlier removal or redflag to better follow the logical.

Comment: @NelsonGon The specifics of how I get to the outlier numbers here is not necessarily part of the issue (i.e. setDT(ols_plot_resid_lev(model)$plot$data)[color %in% c('outlier', 'outlier & leverage'), obs] where model is the output of an lm model, library(olsrr)). What I'm trying to wrap my head around is, is there a faster/more elegant way to edit this data.table for a subset of numbered rows within the subset based on cyl==6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slightly faster solution on this small example

```r
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)
outliernums <- c(1L, 3L, 5L)
cars <- as.data.table(mtcars)
cars[, regflags := 0L]
# gives the same
o1 <- copy(cars)
o1[
  cyl == 6, regflags := ifelse(.I %in% outliernums, regflags + 1L, regflags)]
o2 <- copy(cars)
o2[
  which(cyl == 6)[outliernums], regflags := regflags + 1L]
o3 <- copy(cars)
o3[, regflags := regflags + .I %in% which(cyl == 6)[outliernums]]
all.equal(as.data.frame(o1), as.data.frame(o2), check.attributes = FALSE)
#R [1] TRUE
all.equal(as.data.frame(o1), as.data.frame(o3), check.attributes = FALSE)
#R [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(
  `ifelse` = cars[
    cyl == 6, regflags := ifelse(.I %in% outliernums, regflags + 1L, regflags)],
  `subset method` = cars[
    which(cyl == 6)[outliernums], regflags := regflags + 1L],
  alternative = cars[
    , regflags := regflags + .I %in% which(cyl == 6)[outliernums]],
  times = 1000)
#R Unit: microseconds
#R           expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq       max neval
#R         ifelse 1863.883 1922.782 2038.1044 1939.477 1966.840 19048.795  1000
#R  subset method  482.783  498.551  526.2885  503.652  513.856  2851.244  1000
#R    alternative  279.189  320.928  337.9042  326.493  332.986  2634.665  1000
```

As in the comments, I do not see an obvious application and the code will fail if `which(cyl == 6)` has less than `max(outliernums)`.

Comment: That's great, thanks! In my case, max(outliernums) cannot, by definition exceed it as the outlier row numbers come from that subset in the first place. I relied on the mtcar dataset here just for the sake of simplicity. In terms of application, I'm just running tools that point out outliers for each subset as row numbers within a for loop, so there is definitely an application :)